# You have an error in your SQL syntax; near 'order(cust_id, order_date,order_total, order_state,order_city,order_add,order' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This appears above my page

```
<?php
include("dbconnection.php");

if ($_SESSION["loggedin"] != "true") 
header("Location:memberlogin.php");

$cust_id = $_SESSION["cust_id"];

$result = mysql_query("select customer.*, product.*, order_details.* from customer, product,      
order_details where customer.cust_id=$cust_id and product.pro_id=product.pro_id and    
order_details.order_details_id = order_details.order_details_id")or die(mysql_error());;

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);  
?>
```

In between I have another code for the total

Then this is the codes that appeared below

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["logoutbtn"]))
{
header("Location:logout.php");

}

if(isset($_POST["submitbtn"]))
{
$order_id=rand(1000,9999);
$order_date=date("Y-m-d"); 
$order_state=$_POST["order_state"];
$order_city=$_POST["order_city"];
$order_add=$_POST["order_add"];
$order_post=$_POST["order_post"];

echo ("insert into `order`
(cust_id, order_date, order_total, order_state, order_city, order_add, 
order_post)
values('$cust_id','$order_date', 
'$order_total', '$order_state', '$order_city','$order_add','$order_post')")or die(mysql_error());
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Order recorded.");
    </script>
<?php
header("Location:orderview3.php");
}

?>
```

And I have the error that says 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order(cust_id, order_date,order_total, order_state,order_city,order_add,order' at line 1

Comment: When asking SQL syntax questions its usually better if you extract the generated SQL and post only that (instead of "obfuscating" your SQL within the programming language). In most of the cases you probably see the error yourself then anyway.

Comment: I cannot see how the error message relates to the code provided!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code

```
<?php
include("dbconnection.php");

if ($_SESSION["loggedin"] != "true") {
header("Location:memberlogin.php");
}

$cust_id = $_SESSION["cust_id"];

$result = mysql_query("select customer.*, product.*, order_details.* from customer, product,      
order_details where customer.cust_id=$cust_id and product.pro_id=product.pro_id and    
order_details.order_details_id = order_details.order_details_id")or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);  
?>
```

And use this guide >> http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_syntax.asp

Answer (score 1):

You are using single quotes around column names:

```
$insertQuery=mysql_query("insert into 'order'('cust_id', 'order_date', 'order_total',    
'order_state', 'order_city', 'order_add', 'order_post')values('$cust_id','$order_date', 
'$order_total', '$order_state', '$order_city','$order_add','$order_post')")
```

Try this instead:

```
$insertQuery=mysql_query("insert into `order` (`cust_id`, `order_date`, `order_total`,    
`order_state`, `order_city`, `order_add`, `order_post`)values('$cust_id','$order_date', 
'$order_total', '$order_state', '$order_city','$order_add','$order_post')")
```

Or you can remove them completely if you are sure they aren't reserved words and they don't have spaces or other such silly things in them:

```
$insertQuery=mysql_query("insert into `order`
(cust_id, order_date, order_total, order_state, order_city, order_add, 
order_post)
values('$cust_id','$order_date', 
'$order_total', '$order_state', '$order_city','$order_add','$order_post')")
```

Lastly, this assumes that you do indeed have all the variables set correctly at the time you try to run the query. If you try to insert a value that is empty, the SQL will end up like `insert into someTable values ('someValue','')` which will generate an error as well.

Edit: To echo out the data do this:

```
echo ("insert into `order`
(cust_id, order_date, order_total, order_state, order_city, order_add, 
order_post)
values('$cust_id','$order_date', 
'$order_total', '$order_state', '$order_city','$order_add','$order_post')");
```

And then edit your question and add the output you see. This will probably solve the riddle for us.

Comment: Can you echo out the query to see what values you are trying to use in your query? Also, I still had single quotes around the table name, which I have corrected. Those need to be removed or changed to backticks as well.

Comment: When you said echo the query as in the database? or the rest of the codes? Actually my first attempt have no single quotes.

Comment: <?php
   $x=1;
   
   $order_total=5.00;
   $order_stotal=$row["order_stotal"];
   $result = mysql_query("select product.*,order_details.* from product,order_details 
   where order_details.cust_id = $cust_id and      order_details.pro_id= product.pro_id ");
   while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  
   {
   ?>

Comment: after that i included this
 <?php 
   $x++;
   $order_total +=$order_stotal;
   } 
   ?>

to echo it i place this

<?php
     
     echo number_format($order_total,2);
     ?>

Comment: It ran, but nothing came out. It just continued the function to another page.

Comment: I found out the problem.. It's because I added the "$insertQuery=mysql_query" and changed it to just "mysql_query"

thanks a lot for your time and effort fluffeh. Couldnt have done it without u

Comment: @Jason, don't forget to accept this answer `:)`. It's how we express appreciation on Stack Overflow.